# Creating a Horizontal Parallax navigation

Tags: ios, user-interface

Need some suggestion. I am trying to create an interface as shown in the attached image. So its a horizontal parallax effect. Have you guys created something similar and give me some idea on how to proceed. Any library which can be used? Catch here is the element in RED which stretches across multiple views. 
[image]

Another idea around this, do you think it would make more sense to have one view where i can show just part of the view based on user navigation. My only concern with this is it may become more complex if i have to support multiple display sizes.

Comment: check it will help https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip                            https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented something like this with nested collection views.  The top level horizontally scrolling collection view would have a custom layout object that added a decoration view holding your background behind the items.

You can setup the layout object to invalidate its layout on bounds changes, and pan around the decoration view position relative to the content offset of the collection view to get the parallax effect.

Then you would just need a collection view cell with a nested vertically scrolling collection view in it, which you could create 3 of (or however many you wanted).